# Disabling sentbox in postfix over Squirrelmail

Tags: centos, postfix, logging, squirrelmail

I have installed **POSTFIX** over `Squirrelmail` on CentOS Linux...

The services I have ran are:

```
service httpd
service ssl
service mysql
service postfix
service saslauthd
service dovecot
```

I have installed POSTFIX on centOS server..I want to know how could I disabling all logs on postfix when I send email...
logs existed on server and even in my **sentbox** from `SquirrelMail`.

How can I send mail but nothing go to my sentbox?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just you should know a trick...

you can do:

```
cd /home/bobby/Maildir && chmod -w .Sent/
```

That works!!!